# Xna 2D overlay text in 3D?

Tags: c#, 3d, xna

How would I go about drawing 2D text in Xna while my game is in 3D. Basically I want it to overlay over the screen, not draw it in a certain position in the 3D environment.

Comment: This may help: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/610681-overlaying-textimage-on-a-2d-image-using-direct3d/

Comment: I want XNA studio not Direct3D

Comment: I was referring to the concept. Draw a rectangle with a depth of next to nothing (1) and place it vertical to the camera.

Answer (score 2):

The SpriteBatch, documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.aspx), will allow you to write 2D text, check a tutorial like [this one](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2D/Writing_text.php). See [DrawString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.drawstring.aspx). [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447673.aspx)'s a simple example from Microsoft.